# USB Accessory Activity changing the UI: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, usb, android-activity

I'm just wondering if there is a efficient solution to this issue.

I'm developing USB Accessory HW to connect to Android devices. My Android App's activity creates an instance of my Dongle class which takes care of the USB comms, in a receiver thread. The activity also passes an instance of itself to the Dongle as it provides a callback for the Dongle class upon message reception.

So now you want to let the HW do it's thing, the Dongle class will listen for messages and inform the main Activity, via the callback, what's happening, so that it can adjust it's view to reflect what's happening. Error: **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views**.

I could create a brand new activity every time the Hardware, or the user, changes something but I'm going to leave a forest of activities in my wake. (AFAIK Google frown on killing activity forcibly) I don't see any way around this, that is in any way efficient. I could have the original thread just sit there polling for USB changes but that's going to slow down the whole system.

I was trying to change the layout with "activity.setContentView(R.layout.main)" maybe I could forget layout files and generate UI's in SW. I'd still be in the wrong thread. Hmmm

Anybody with any ideas I'd be really glad to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public Handler in the activity that you want to change and post Runables in it

Comment: Will they still not enter the Handler from a different thread from that which started the activity? Sorry Yes you're right. The other thread posts into the Activity's message queue.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, sorry, what's the point ?